# Using PivotTable.js with aurelia and asp.net core

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, aurelia, pivottable.js

My Project is setup based on ASP.Net Core with aurelia, as in this video by Rob Eisenberg https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2017/T6032

Now I'm trying to use PivotTable.js plugin with it.
It has an example function:

```
$(function () {
  $("#output").pivot(
    [
      { color: "blue", shape: "circle" },
      { color: "red", shape: "triangle" }
    ],
    {
      rows: ["color"],
      cols: ["shape"]
    }
  );
});
```

I tried it first in a simple html page with inline script tags and it worked fine. 
In aurelia project, I wrap it in a load() function that gets triggered on a button click:

```
//playground.html
<button id="btn1" click.trigger="load()">Load</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

............

```
//playground.ts
import $ from 'jquery'

export class Playground {
   load() {
    $(function () {
        $('#output').pivot(
    ...
   }
 }
```

I installed it with npm, now it looks like I'm having problem referencing it correctly. I tested with having it directly in the script tag of my viewmodel

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="pivot.js"></script>
```

It keeps throwing "pivot is not a function" error like below:

```
    jQuery.Deferred exception: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_jquery___default(...)(...).pivot is not a function app/components/play/playground/Playground.prototype.load/<@http://localhost:63822/dist/app.js?v=Co4Zys-nKtxDfRHuYeQtAcAzgXG9rRHqPqkwN0CzgJQ:27236:13

   mightThrow@http://localhost:63822    /dist/vendor.js?v=8kh55HdjmafGVyQfWaHURccoz4Vi-HAb9obSOc7CDCk:14851:21

     resolve/</process<@http://localhost:63822/dist/vendor.js?v=8kh55HdjmafGVyQfWaHURccoz4Vi-HAb9obSOc7CDCk:14919:12

     undefined
    vendor.js:15128:3
    TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_jquery___default(...)(...).pivot is not a function
```

My Index.cshtml seemed to look into dist folder for scripts so I moved the pivot.js files into dist and added script tags there

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/dist/pivot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/dist/pivot.min.js"></script>
```

I have added `jquery` and `jquery-ui` as dependencies and `devdependencies` (I do have doubts whether this is correct way to do it) in `package.json`:

```
    "devDependencies": {
          "jquery": "^3.2.1",
          "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1"
          ....
     },
      "dependencies": [
       { "jquery": "^3.2.1" },
       { "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1" } 
      ]
```

Also added a jquery as a plugin to webpack.config.js as suggested for some another plugin to make that work.

```
       plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery'
        })
```

I tried adding cdn links to `jquery` in script tags in my viewmodel. None of these changes have changed the error message. How should I be referencing this and similar `jquery` plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably should add an import statement
`import 'pivottable';`
after the jquery import
if the npm package is right, this should do.

it is more of a webpack question than aurelia.
googling "webpack jquery pivottable" should get you more answers.

Comment: After adding "pivottable": "^2.19.0" to devDependencies to package.json, and importing pivottable like your suggestion, I got the output in plain readonly text, not interactive as shown in examples for .pivot() function. When I imported "import 'jquery-ui' and used .pivotUI function, I got "An error occurred rendering the pivottable UI without much description. I replaced import $ from 'jquery' with import $ from 'jquery-ui', that threw eror: TypeError: name.split is not a function

Comment: Looks like the plain text was css not being imported correctly. I could get it to work using <link rel..> reference, which is fine for now although later I will try loading it through import. 
Regarding pivotUI, I wasn't able to get it to work even with loading jqueryUI via <script> tag. Any direction on that would be appreciated. I am searching webpack jquery pivottable, haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: jquery UI relies on $ being a global, i guess..
for start you could try add jquery and jquery  ui as <script> tags and jquery should come before ui.
if that works, the direction you are looking for is 
importing jquery and ui in your  viewmodel as well as css
but you'll have to fiddle with webpack  and it's provide plugin to make jquery look like a global

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/

Comment: I had too many references to jquery-ui all over my code while trying to get this to work. I started removing them and at some point, it started working for me. Currently I have 'webpack-jquery-ui' in devdependencies of package.json and import 'pivottable/pivot.min.js'. I also found I will have to use pivot.js code as is, without making changes as it gets refreshed from the source everytime npm reloads, however I am able to load its css locally and edit it. Although I do not know the exact steps, your suggestions did help me get further.

Comment: opinionated old libraries are hard to integrate with anything. 
glad to hear you got unblocked.
join aurelia's forums https://discourse.aurelia.io to keep in touch with community

Answer (score 1):

I fought a while to get pivottable.js work with webpack and Aurelia. You will need the following NPM packages:

```
jquery
jquery-ui-dist
pivottable
```

The "normal" jquery-ui package did not work for me.

In your typescript file, use the following imports:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui';
import 'pivottable';
```

Then you can use the `$('#output').pivotUI(...)` function. In your template HTML file, you will need to import the CSS:

```
<require from="pivottable/dist/pivot.css"></require>
```

Using this setup and the same `ProvidePlugin` code, I am able to use pivottable.js within webpack without additional `script` tags.

Comment: For me, it was 'webpack-jquery-ui' that worked. So I did not try jquery-ui-dist. Someone else might benefit from it.